# ASP.NET Session Timeout with sessionState config set

Tags: asp.net

I have the line :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="960"/>
```

in my Web.config file but still the sessions are timing out after about 25 minutes. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have any firewalls, load balancers?

Answer (score 0):

Check the application pool configuration. Assuming you have IIS7, go to the application's pool advenced properties, then check the Process Model Idle Timeout property.